# Which are the implicit objects available by default on templates?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to create a plugin for **Play Framework 2.0** (latest code in Github as of today, 10th December 2011). The plugin must render some data in the view. To avoid forcing users to modify all the templates, I created a tag that will retrieve and render the relevant data.

To avoid concurrency issues that data should be stored along an identifier for the user. This identifier only needs to be valid during a request (session id, request itself, etc), after the request ends the information would be discarded.

The issue is that neither Request, RequestHeader nor Session are available as implicit values inside a Scala template. So, **which are the implicit values available in a template**?

If there are none I can use, do you have any suggestion on how to obtain a value that I can access from templates and controllers (without requiring a user to modify neither the controller or the template) and that can be generated in a per-request basis?

Comment: Hello Pere, was the answer ok for you ? In that case, don't forget to accept it because I saw several questions in other forums that your question may help. Thanks

Comment: sorry, not entering as often lately :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it was a problem to me too...

Actually, they *could* have one `implicit` but still that you have to **add** it to the parameters list and to **declare** the needed object as `implicit` in the Action.

Here is how I did:

#### template

```
// **FIRST** add the needed implicit parameter to the template (the whole template will be created as a function will the related parameters, incl. curryed parameters list are handled) 
@(stuff:models.MyStuff)(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[Any])

@import helper._

@main("Home"){

}
```

#### controller

```
object Main extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    // **SECONDLY** declare the request as implicit.
    implicit request =>
      Ok(views.html.index(MyStuff()))
    }
}
```

#### More?

Since one single `implicit` parameter is valid, you could wrap your needed object in a dedicated structure and declare it as `implicit`.

Comment: that's good.. now what if my controller is Java?  there is no implicit

Comment: SO sorry, I didn't try Play with Java yet... maybe you could just define the request as parameter explicitly?

Comment: Actually it appears the variables session, request, response and flash are magically available in the scala template ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I've found

- `session` which is a [play.mvc.Http.Session](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.Session.html) object
- `request` which is a [play.mvc.Http.Request](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html) object
- `response` which is a [play.mvc.Http.Response](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.Response.html) object
- `flash` which is a [play.mvc.Http.Flash](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.Flash.html) object
- `lang` which is a [play.i18n.Lang](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/i18n/Lang.html) object

are still available, while the implicit objects `errors`, `out`, `params`, and `play` from 1.x have been removed. It looks like this list is determined by [play.mvc.Http.Context.Implicit](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.Implicit.html), whose javadoc says "Import in templates to get implicit HTTP context". So I'm fairly confident this is the entire list of what's available automatically.

There is also a `@Messages` thing which seems to replace the `messages` implicit object along with the `&{'my.message.key'}` syntax from 1.x. It's actually shorthand for a method invocation rather than being an implicit object. You can do `@Messages("my.message.key")` which invokes [play.Messages.get(String,Object...)](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/i18n/Messages.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), or you can force a certain language with things like `@Messages("index.title")(Lang("es"))` or `@Messages("index.title")(Lang("es-ar"))` which invoke [play.Messages.get(Lang,String,Object...)](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/i18n/Messages.html#get(play.i18n.Lang,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).